# angular material router navigation with respect to root

Tags: angular, angular-material, router

I am into a situation in my project where clicking a button fails to navigate with exception:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'workarea/homepage'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'workarea/homepage'
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1466)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.es5.js:1441)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at LastSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1466)
```

it is trying to navigate to workarea/home which does not exist and that is correct. i don't know why it is trying it that way. what i want it to navigate to /home rather workarea/home.  What fix i need for that. the router file looks like below:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [ 
    {
        path: '',
        component: LoginPageComponent
    },
     {
        path: 'homepage',
        component: DynamicHomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'workarea',
        component: WorkareaPageComponent
    },
     {
        path: 'workarea-typeb',
        component: WorkareaTypebPageComponent
    }

];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your router link, add a forward slash `/` before the link

instead of

```
routerLink='home'
```

try

```
routerLink='/home'
```